# SNI for Multiple Hosts on Lighttpd

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, ssl-certificate, lighttpd, sni

Inherited lighttpd server, I'm somewhat clueless on it. Trying to use SNI to install a 3rd SSL cert without another IP. Currently the SSL config in lighttpd.conf looks like so:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/private/domain1.com.pem"
  ssl.ca-file = "/etc/ssl/private/chain.cer"
  $HTTP["host"] == "domain2.com" {          
     ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/private/domain2.com.pem"
     ssl.ca-file = "/etc/ssl/private/chain.cer"
  }
}
```

Trying to add the 3rd cert, like so:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
  ssl.engine = "enable"
  ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/private/domain1.com.pem"
  ssl.ca-file = "/etc/ssl/private/chain.cer"
  $HTTP["host"] == "domain2.com" {          
     ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/private/domain2.com.pem"
     ssl.ca-file = "/etc/ssl/private/chain.cer"
  }
  $HTTP["host"] == "domain3.com" {          
     ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/private/domain3.com.pem"
  }
}
```

Something not working about it, lighttpd won't start/restart when the config looks like this.

Comment: *won't start/restart* - in this case I would expect that you will find log messages which indicate a problem. Did you look?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much in the log - just that it was stopped and then started again (after I removed the extra lines).

Comment: so it did actually start based on the log files? because you've wrote that it did not start.

Comment: As I wrote, it started after I removed the new lines. Can't just leave the server sitting there not running. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your domain3.com.pem file correct?

Lighttpd uses a slightly less common construction where the `ssl.pemfile` should not only contain the signed certificate that your CA returned to you, it should also contain the associated private key.

It should look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ABC...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
ABC...
-----END PRIVATE KEY----
```

Comment: THANK YOU. My key and crt were reversed in the pem. Fixed the file and it worked.